# Why would someone ask me to insert a javascript on my domain/website prior to buy?

Tags: javascript

I have been developing sites for years now and today I got a request that I found pretty odd.  I would like to get some advice on this matter.

This person sent me some JS code and asked me to insert it on my website.  This is the reason he gives me:

> we need to test your domain, and if we purchase your domain

I would like to know what you guys think about this. This is the first time I've gotten such a request and I have my doubts. To be clear, I do have a website installed on the domain that he wants me to insert this code.
He says that the code is an image.

```
!function(){
    var imgadd =["padding:0px;margin:0px;height:auto;-webkit-border-radius: 0px!important","data:image/jpeg;base64,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"]
    document.writeln('<a href="http://gametrends.info/"'+'style="'+imgadd.[0]+'"'+'target="_blank">');
    document.write('<img' +' src="'+imgadd[1]+'">'+'</a>');
}();
```

Comment: So... A random person on the internet sent you some code and asked you to execute it, and you're asking us whether or not you should?

Comment: Its not analytics code.  I edited my question and added the code.  I did remove some of the middle part since it was too long to paste here but I think the first and last part are the most important.

Comment: @Jaromanda X  -  It may sound like a stupid question... sorry lol ... but this is the first time I get suck request .. usually they would ask for google analytics ect ... but this guy want me to insert this file in the main folder.   I have make LOTS of website but for this situation its a first ... So I just wanted advise on if I shuld upload that file or not.  I know it sounds fishy and I dont see how this can show him the stats...  Once I upload the file he want the link of that file so that he can "test"

Comment: I'm messing with you - will remove silly comments ... by the way, that "image" is highly suspect

Comment: @Jaromanda X - Thanks :)   ok so in the end you would not consider doing so.  You know of any way that he can actually test the domain stats or anything like this with this kind of code?

Comment: I ran the code here: http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html and its gives me an error...

Comment: I really can't see how adding a link and a data uri image can be used for anything worthwhile ... unless someone clicks on it

Comment: @MartinTurgeon Remove the dot between `imgadd.[0]`. The base64 also doesnt seem to be valid, but if it is a non-public file then it doesnt matter.

Comment: Thanks!  This is why I asked because I cannot see any reason to do this lol ... but others keep saying that its just an image.  He says I can add it in subfolder as well so that it dont affect the website.  I just dont see the point and this is why I found that request odd...

Comment: I am getting more info right now from him I will share with you guys.

Comment: Detailed reason he want me to do this :
In advertising sector, there are some recognized tools to surveil the ads. About ads, there are many different types of ads, our ads via JS tag, we can receive traffic through this JS. But some recognized tools are very strict with JS ads. As a result, we want to do a test with your domain/site before we purchase it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you add it to a new file with only this as the content, then it  isnt any form of security issue. It is done to verify You control the domain.

There is no way they can use this to gather analytics about your users, so you're safe on that front as well.

**Do not add it to an existing page, as it will replace all content.**

Comment: I have added the code for better view...   This person is not "random" as he bough from me in the past.  I am a website seller.

Comment: ok thanks !  so I could add this in a subfolder? and it would be safe?

Comment: @MartinTurgeon Yes. You should wrap it in `<script>` tags probably for it to be run. html and body tags are optional as of html5

Comment: Perfect Thanks !   I will try this and update you guys with the results :)

Comment: This is the detailed reason he just gave me : 
In advertising sector, there are some recognized tools to surveil the ads. About ads, there are many different types of ads, our ads via JS tag, we can receive traffic through this JS. But some recognized tools are very strict with JS ads. As a result, we want to do a test with your domain/site before we purchase it.

Comment: so far seams like its fine ... we just see the code from here but they say they can see the image .. :)